# IOS 6 Routing App Coverage File in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, ios6, geojson

When I submit my app Routing File in itunes connect I got this error message:

```
JSON file you uploaded was invalid. Errors : Each set of coordinates provided must be valid : [Ljava.lang.Object;@1f02c024
```

**This is the content of the geoJson file:**

```
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates": 
[[45.56497960813695, -74.22161340332036],[45.823011917542566, -73.46767663574224],[45.47356846799377, -73.30562829589849],[45.34051720106048, -73.51299523925786],[45.56497960813695, -74.22161340332036]]}
```

I can't see where is the problem with this coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Multipolygon coordinates are arrays of arrays of arrays: [[[x, y], ...]. Plus, it looks like your coordinates are swapped. It needs to be [easting, northing](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions) ( or longitude, latitude) just like with [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#point).